# Separar una columna en varias columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Alguien sabe como dividir un campo en varias columnas? 
Tengo esta query:

```
select  C.IdCampana As IdCampana, C.LineaCampana as LineaCampana, CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdMarca as IdMarca, CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdModelo as IdModelo, 
CampanaEquipo = STUFF((    select ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(Descripcion)) 
from (
select A.IdCampana, A.LineaCampana, A.SecuencialComposicion, Descripcion = STUFF((
select  '+ ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(B.Descripcion)) + Space(1)
from   CM_VH_CampanaComposicionDetalle as B
where  B.IdCampana = A.IdCampana and B.LineaCampana = A.LineaCampana and B.SecuencialComposicion = A.SecuencialComposicion 
for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ' + BONO ' + case CM_VH_Campana.Moneda when 'LO' then 'S/.' when 'EX' then '$' end + Space(1) + LTRIM(STR(CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Bono, 10,2)) + Space(1) + 'ó'
from   CM_VH_CampanaComposicion                
join   CM_VH_CampanaComposicionDetalle AS A    on     A.IdCampana = CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.IdCampana and A.LineaCampana = CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.LineaCampana and A.SecuencialComposicion= CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Secuencial
where  CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Composicion = 'BNA'
group by     CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Bono,A.IdCampana,A.LineaCampana, A.SecuencialComposicion
)            AS     CampanaComposicion
where  CampanaComposicion.IdCampana = C.IdCampana and CampanaComposicion.LineaCampana = C.LineaCampana
for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
from         CM_VH_CampanaComposicion C
left join CM_VH_CampanaDetalle 
on  CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdCampana = C.IdCampana and CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.Linea = c.LineaCampana
left join CM_VH_Campana on CM_VH_Campana.IdCampana = CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdCampana
where        (CM_VH_Campana.Procedencia = 1) and (CM_VH_Campana.Estado = 2) and (convert(datetime,convert (char(10), GETDATE(), 101)) between  CM_VH_Campana.FechaInicio and CM_VH_Campana.FechaFin) and C.Composicion = 'BNA'
group by     C.IdCampana, C.LineaCampana,CM_VH_Campana.Moneda, CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdMarca,CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdModelo
```

Y me arroja esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera dividir el campo de CampanaEquipo en varias columnas asi:

```
IdCampana   LineaCampana   IdMarca   IdModelo   CampanaEquipo
2           1              1         373        Radio Touchscreen (AVH-A2150BT) + Cámara de retroceso + Sensor de retroceso  
2           1              1         373        BONO $ 1500.00 Radio Touchscreen (AVH-A2150BT) 
2           1              1         373        Faros Neblineros  + BONO $ 1500.00
```

Y asi sucesivamente para los otros registros(solo quisiera ayuda para el primer registro de la Fila LineaCampana 1)

Comment: Por favor tu consulta como texto, no hay necesidad de usar imágenes

Answer (score 1):

¿Cuál es tu versión de sql server?
En 2016 se introdujo split_String con el operador Apply.

[Separar cadenas split_string](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/string-split-separar-cadenas/)

Si tu versión es anterior, tienes entre otras opciones, la función de Jeff Moden para separar cadenas

[Delimited split 8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Como ya te han indicado, si pegas el texto de tu query, será mucho más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Tengo la version 2008. PD: Ya coloque el query en text.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero crear una función que te permita separar strings por un char.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
    (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
-- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
            ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
   E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
   E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (
             SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER    BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
            ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just     once for each delimiter)
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL
             SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) =  @pDelimiter
            ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
             SELECT s.N1,
                    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-  s.N1,8000)
               FROM cteStart s
            )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the  final element when no delimiter is found.
SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Con la función, puedes utilizarla envolviendo completamente tu query, y con la salida de la tabla derivada utilizar el operador apply, pasándole como parámetros el campo para separar y el carácter serparador.

```
SELECT *, fn.* FROM (
SELECT C.IdCampana AS IdCampana
 , C.LineaCampana AS LineaCampana
 , CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdMarca AS IdMarca
 , CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdModelo AS IdModelo
 , CampanaEquipo = STUFF(
(
SELECT ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(Descripcion))
FROM
(
    SELECT A.IdCampana
         , A.LineaCampana
         , A.SecuencialComposicion
         , Descripcion = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT '+ ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(B.Descripcion)) + SPACE(1)
        FROM CM_VH_CampanaComposicionDetalle AS B
               WHERE B.IdCampana = A.IdCampana
                     AND B.LineaCampana = A.LineaCampana
                     AND B.SecuencialComposicion = A.SecuencialComposicion FOR XML    PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') + ' + BONO ' + CASE CM_VH_Campana.Moneda
                                    WHEN 'LO'
                                    THEN 'S/.'
                                    WHEN 'EX'
                                    THEN '$'
                                END + SPACE(1) +   LTRIM(STR(CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Bono, 10, 2)) + SPACE(1) + 'ó'
    FROM CM_VH_CampanaComposicion
         JOIN CM_VH_CampanaComposicionDetalle AS A ON A.IdCampana =   CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.IdCampana
                                                      AND A.LineaCampana = CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.LineaCampana
                                                      AND A.SecuencialComposicion   = CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Secuencial
           WHERE CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Composicion = 'BNA'
           GROUP BY CM_VH_CampanaComposicion.Bono
                  , A.IdCampana
                  , A.LineaCampana
                  , A.SecuencialComposicion
) AS CampanaComposicion
       WHERE CampanaComposicion.IdCampana = C.IdCampana
             AND CampanaComposicion.LineaCampana = C.LineaCampana FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
FROM CM_VH_CampanaComposicion C
 LEFT JOIN CM_VH_CampanaDetalle ON CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdCampana = C.IdCampana
                                   AND CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.Linea = c.LineaCampana
 LEFT JOIN CM_VH_Campana ON CM_VH_Campana.IdCampana =  CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdCampana
   WHERE(CM_VH_Campana.Procedencia = 1)
        AND (CM_VH_Campana.Estado = 2)
        AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)) BETWEEN    CM_VH_Campana.FechaInicio AND CM_VH_Campana.FechaFin)
        AND C.Composicion = 'BNA'
   GROUP BY C.IdCampana
          , C.LineaCampana
          , CM_VH_Campana.Moneda
          , CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdMarca
          , CM_VH_CampanaDetalle.IdModelo
) AS O
CROSS APPLY dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K] (O.CampanaEquipo, '+') as fn
```

Aún así hay muchas incongruencias, con la información que muestras en tú código.
Yo diría que Stuff no existe en 2008. Tampoco le veo sentido a utilizar stuff y xml_Path para concatenar algo que luego quieres separar.

Como no das datos, de lo que tienes, realmente y la consulta tiene su complejidad, tampoco te puedo ayudar mucho más.